# How do I optimize this DB2 Query Where Clause?

Tags: sql, database, performance, db2

I've got a query here that looks for users authorized to a project and it's written in a way that is human readable, however I'm looking to optimize a DB2 query.  Is it possible to utilize some nested selects or some clever joining of tables to make this query perform better?

```
SELECT * 
FROM PROJECT p, USER_EMAIL_ACCESS uea, USER_EMAIL e
WHERE (
    uea.PROJECT_ID = p.ID and
    uea.USER_EMAIL_ID = l.ID and
    uea.STATE_ID = 1 and 
    e.USER_ID = 100 and 
    e.STATE_ID = 1 and
    p.STATE_ID = 1
)
```

Comment: What indexes exists on the tables?  At least the join columns should be indexed, and the runstats should be recent.  Are you sure you want all columns from all three tables? Do you know how to view the access-plan and interpret it ?

Comment: To optimize select only columns you need and not just "*"

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
PROJECT p 
inner join USER_EMAIL_ACCESS uea on (uea.PROJECT_ID, uea.STATE_ID)  = (p.ID, p.STATE_ID) 
inner join USER_EMAIL e on e.STATE_ID = uea.STATE_ID and e.USER_ID = 100
WHERE p.STATE_ID = 1
```